# My air conditioning will not turn off. The temp is set at 75 the thermostat reads 77

Tags: hvac

The thermostat is set at 75, the thermostat reads 77 degrees but the unit will not quit running. My intuition thinks bad thermostat. Our HVAC professional changed our thermostat out last year.
HELP

Comment: What you want the thermostat to turn goo 2 degrees prior to the set point ? Turn the dead band up to 5 degrees and come back and complain when it turns off two soon... VTC!

Comment: "Dead band" is also known as "swing".

Comment: Welcome. Your question will likely be closed because 1) you haven't really explained the problem or circumstances well, and 2) you haven't told us anything about your hardware or climate. Please revise to do so.

Comment: Yes,what you have described is working as intended. It would be like complaining that when you put bread in a toaster  it comes out warmer...

Comment: I have just voted to close it. There are too many speculative answers already, with a brand new one today. It needs more information from the Op. This probably has not happened as some of the above comments are not too kind.

Answer (score 9):

For air conditioning, Set at 75 and reading a temperature of 77 means it still needs to cool 2 more degrees before shutting off, since it's cooling, or trying to.

Either it's hot and you're at capacity for the machine, or it's not cooling effectively and may need service, if it's not cooling as effectively as it used to.

What you have posted does not appear to indicate any problem related to the thermostat.

Answer (score 3):

If the A/C unit will not cool to a given set point, the thermostat is not the problem. Your problem is not enough cooling capacity which would indicate a service problem. (unit too old or too small, or in need of service). It is time to call an HVAC specialist to check the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change the mode setting from **Heat** to **Cool**.

Change the fan setting from **On** to **Auto**.

Comment: I think it would be obvious if the unit was running in heat mode. Also, the fan setting won't affect cooling outcome if it's not reaching the set point.

Comment: Not if the ambient temperature was within the thermostat's hysteresis.   The symptoms described could very well be a user not familiar with how most thermostats work.  I pointed out the obvious...just in case.

Answer (score 0):

If it's 90° or higher outside this will happen. Change your thermostat to 77 or 78 it will shut off. Letting it stay on 75 will not shut off durning the day until the sun goes down.

Comment: Doesn't that depend a lot on the amount of insulation in the structure, the quality of the windows, and the unit itself? It seems to be a pretty bold statement to say that AC will never shut off if it's > 90° outside. Especially since mine does... This needs some supporting evidence to give it credibility.,